# To continue tasks in c# only when DTS complete their job

Tags: c#, dts

How to ask the application to only continue their tasks when the dts job is completed?

Currently there is a feature that involves transforming the result file of one DTS.
But for the first time, the transformation completed correctly. But the subsequent time would result in incomplete file being tranform where i guess is the transformation happened before the DTS completed. What might be the cause to this issue?

Comment: `await` the previous tasks?

Comment: @FrankerZ any example or how it works?

Comment: Not without some code on your end.